# Controlling placement of empty lattice panels

Tags: r, lattice

When plotting fewer panels than the full grid you get a gap without a panel. Most lattice functions puts the gap in the top right, but I would like to have it in the lower right, as `marginal.plot` does (see the picture). Is there a way to make other lattice functions do the same?

[image: Example from the marignal.plot help page]

I know the panel order is decided by the order of the factor levels of the conditioning variable, or by using the `index.cond` argument, but that does not help me here. I have tried to decipher the code of `marginal.plot`, but haven't been able to figure it out, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: See `?grid.arrange` in `gridExtra` package.

Comment: Interesting package. It is not quite what I had in mind this time but will sure come in handy if I try to combine plots of different types, e.g. grid and lattice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `as.table=TRUE` option should do this for most lattice plots by filling in the top row first instead of the bottom row.

Comment: Yay! Knew it shouldn't be too hard, but couldn't figure it out, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The `as.table=` argument is really there to let users specify the corner from which laying down of panels begins (i.e. top-left or bottom-left). It thus gives you only limited and incidental control over where panels are and are not plotted.

For greater control over panel placement, use the `skip=` argument (perhaps in concert with `as.table=TRUE`):

```
# 'skip' plotting of the central panel.
# Note: skip <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0) or even 'skip <- 1:9 %in% 5' would also work
skip <- c(F,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F) 
xyplot(lat ~ long | Depth, data = quakes, skip = skip, layout = c(3,3))
```

[image]